# PHPExcel : Splitting an Excel document sheet by sheet

Tags: phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel library for many Excel manipulations, combined with PHP/MySQL.
That helps me well.

But I can't figure how to split an Excel document sheet by sheet,where each sheet is created as a new Excel document.

I also need, at the same time, to delete the empty lines which are in the original document in the new Excel documents produced (cleaning up the final docs).

What's the best way to do it ?

All your experiences are greatly appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the way of what I wanted.

Here is a solution (maybe not the best way, but it works fine enough) :

```
$file = $_POST['file'];
$filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

require_once 'phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$xls = new PHPExcel();
$xlsReader= new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$xlsTemplate = $xlsReader->load($file);

$sheet1 = $xlsTemplate->getSheetByName('Sheet1');
$xls->addExternalSheet($sheet1,0);
$xls->removeSheetByIndex(1);
$xlsWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($xls);
$xlsWriter->save($filename."_Sheet1.xls");

$sheet2 = $xlsTemplate->getSheetByName('Sheet2');
$xls->addExternalSheet($sheet2,0);
$xls->removeSheetByIndex(1);
$xlsWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($xls);
$xlsWriter->save($filename."_Sheet2.xls");

$sheet3 = $xlsTemplate->getSheetByName('Sheet3');
$xls->addExternalSheet($sheet3,0);
$xls->removeSheetByIndex(1);
$xlsWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($xls);
$xlsWriter->save($filename."_Sheet3.xls");

$sheet4 = $xlsTemplate->getSheetByName('Sheet4');
$xls->addExternalSheet($sheet4,0);
$xls->removeSheetByIndex(1);
$xlsWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($xls);
$xlsWriter->save($filename."_Sheet4.xls");

$sheet5 = $xlsTemplate->getSheetByName('Sheet5');
$xls->addExternalSheet($sheet5,0);
$xls->removeSheetByIndex(1);
$xlsWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($xls);
$xlsWriter->save($filename."_Sheet5.xls");

$sheet6 = $xlsTemplate->getSheetByName('Sheet6');
$xls->addExternalSheet($sheet6,0);
$xls->removeSheetByIndex(1);
$xlsWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($xls);
$xlsWriter->save($filename."_Sheet6.xls");
```

Then, my original Excel file, containing 6 sheets is now splitted in 6 Excel files, as I wanted.

As you can see, it was not so hard to release, but the documentation is so confusing...

Hope this can help.